# Can you give an example of why exactly a Java abstract method cannot exist in a non-abstract class?

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract-methods

I'd like a real-world type example that illustrates why exactly a Java abstract method cannot exist in a non-abstract class.

I appreciate the reasons why that can't happen - abstract classes forcing implementation of any abstract methods contained in them - but an understandable concrete example would really help me reason it out in my head, many thanks.

Comment: Why that can't happen? Because it's not allowed. I'm not sure how an example would help you.

Comment: There are abstract and non-abstract classes. A non-abstract class must not have abstract methods. You want an abstract method => you need an abstract class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the key differences between an abstract class and a non-abstract class is the fact that you cannot create an instance of an abstract class. This prevents a situation where a method with no definition gets called.

So if we had the following abstract class:

```java
abstract class Elephant {    // abstract class

    public String getName() {
        return "Ollie";
    }

    public abstract void walk();   // abstract method

}
```

Then the following would be illegal:

```java
Elephant e = new Elephant();   // error
```

Because `Elephant` is abstract and it cannot be instantiated.

But say for argument sake, that we make `Elephant` non-abstract but it is allowed to still have the abstract method `walk()`. i.e. we change the definition of `Elephant` to:

```java
class Elephant {    // non-abstract class

    public String getName() {
        return "Ollie";
    }

    public abstract void walk();    // abstract method

}
```

Now what should happen if I do the following:

```java
Elephant e = new Elephant();   // legal since Elephant is non-abstract
e.walk();   // oops, we didn't define this anywhere
```

Java compiler won't allow this. You could argue that there are other ways to handle a situation like this, but this simply how the Java language has decided to implement the feature.

Comment: Many thanks, you've answered the question exactly as I asked :) that helps me a lot! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

An abstract class means that the class can't be directly instantiated. If a class has an abstract method, then it can't be directly instantiated since there would be no definition for that method. Therefore, any class with an abstract method IS an abstract class that can't be instantiated. Java simply makes you label it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Like an `abstract` method in a `class`, methods from an `interface` (which are implicitly abstract) allow to model an abstraction. Something that is related to multiple types, but yet every single part acts differently.

Consider a simple vehicle, which can `drive()`, that´s one thing common to vehicles.

```
public interface Vehicle {
    void drive();
}
```

Now, you cannot create a `Vehicle` by itself: `Vehicle v = new Vehicle()`. Consider the task to *build something that can drive*. You just care that it can drive, irrelevant of how excactly it is done. You *talk* of an abstraction, but you **always** need a concrete implementation, something that is actually capable of doing so. That´s why you cannot instantiate an abstract class. It is incomplete, missing some required part that is abstracted.

Therefore, each vehicle drives differently, as the following implementations demonstrate:

```
public class Car implements Vehicle {
    public void drive() {
        if(isEngineTurnedOn()) {
            GearState state = getCurrentGearState();
            if(state == GearState.BACKWARDS) {
                // ...
            } else {
                engine.setSpeed(currentSpeed);
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
}

public class Boat implements Vehicle {
    public void drive() {
        if(isEngineTurnedOn()) {
            rotor.setAngleInDegrees(currentAngle);              
            rotor.setSpeed(currentSpeed);
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then, if you ask again for *something that can drive*, you can hand the caller a `new Car()`, which is capable of doing so. Since the caller is just interested in `drive()`, you could have handed him a `new Boat()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at this "why do I have to provide implementations of my interface?"

And the answer is because interface methods are implicitly `abstract`.  So you **must** provide an implementation (or an empty body).  Otherwise,  you will get a compiler error because there is no method body and thus no legitimate method to call (the JVM would not know how to handle it - for a non void return type, what would it do?).

Now you if you declare that same class as abstract, no implementation is required.
Then you are reduced to your earlier question, for which the answers are the same.  Abstract methods can't be called so it makes no sense to allow the classes that contain them to be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Foreword: I tried to make it simple and logical but this may not be an exact logical explanation but this will surely **help you reason it out in your head**, just know there are rules that you have to follow. In every language you may come across such rules that may seem little confusing, questionable.

Let's try to understand it like this:

A method without definition is incomplete, using an abstract(incomplete) method in a non-abstract(complete) class will add incompleteness to that class and will make that class incomplete. Now you cannot instantiate the class because it is incomplete(abstract).

And this doesn't make sense because you can use abstract class for this, why turn a non-abstract class into abstract. That's why it is not allowed.

But if you want to do something like this, you can add methods with **empty** definition to non-abstract class.